# How to display some specified sections in the navigation bar?

Tags: beamer, headline

How to display some specified sections in the navigation bar. For example, if I completed a set of slides in a project and then want to write another set of it in the same project, I need to rearrange the new sections. How can I prevent the previous sections from being counted? The code is as follows, could you please help me?

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=14mm,text margin right=14mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=hide,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
    \end{frame}
} 

\title{Research Survey 1}
\author{Zhihao Li}
\institute{School of Computer Science and Technology}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\logo{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    }\hskip-.1cm%
}

\show\hss

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\section*{}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%\section*{OUTLINE}

\begin{frame}{OUTLINE}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}

INSERT INTRODUCTION.

\end{frame}

\section{THEORY}

\begin{frame}{THEORY 1}

INSERT THEORY 1.

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{THEORY 2}

INSERT THEORY 2.

\end{frame}

\section{METHOD(S)}

\begin{frame}{METHOD(S)}

INSERT METHOD(S).

\end{frame}

\section{RESULTS}

\begin{frame}{RESULTS}

INSERT RESULTS.

\end{frame}

\section{DISCUSSION}

\begin{frame}{DISCUSSION}

INSERT DISCUSSION.

\end{frame}

\section{CONCLUSIONS}

\begin{frame}{CONCLUSIONS}

INSERT CONCLUSIONS.

\end{frame}

%\section{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\miniframesoff

\nologo
\begin{frame}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

INSERT BIBLIOGRAPHY

\end{frame}

%\section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\begin{frame}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\centering{
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \title{Research Survey 2}
    \section*{}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\miniframeson
\section{NEW INTRODUCTION}
\begin{frame}{NEW INTRODUCTION}
INSERT NEW INTRODUCTION.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a `\part`, then the headline will only display the miniframes in the current part:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=14mm,text margin right=14mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=hide,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
    \end{frame}
} 

\title{Research Survey 1}
\author{Zhihao Li}
\institute{School of Computer Science and Technology}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\logo{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    }\hskip-.1cm%
}

\show\hss

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\section*{}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%\section*{OUTLINE}

\begin{frame}{OUTLINE}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}

INSERT INTRODUCTION.

\end{frame}

\section{THEORY}

\begin{frame}{THEORY 1}

INSERT THEORY 1.

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{THEORY 2}

INSERT THEORY 2.

\end{frame}

\section{METHOD(S)}

\begin{frame}{METHOD(S)}

INSERT METHOD(S).

\end{frame}

\section{RESULTS}

\begin{frame}{RESULTS}

INSERT RESULTS.

\end{frame}

\part{}

\section{DISCUSSION}

\begin{frame}{DISCUSSION}

INSERT DISCUSSION.

\end{frame}

\section{CONCLUSIONS}

\begin{frame}{CONCLUSIONS}

INSERT CONCLUSIONS.

\end{frame}

%\section{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\miniframesoff

\nologo
\begin{frame}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

INSERT BIBLIOGRAPHY

\end{frame}

%\section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\begin{frame}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\centering{
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \title{Research Survey 2}
    \section*{}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\miniframeson
\section{NEW INTRODUCTION}
\begin{frame}{NEW INTRODUCTION}
INSERT NEW INTRODUCTION.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```